# Failed to start bean 'scheduler'; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Trying to configure my Quartz Schedular to run few jobs. Unfortunately running into the below exception on server start.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'scheduler'; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getDelegate(JobStoreSupport.java:3133) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:855) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$1.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:838) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3703) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3701) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:834) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:690) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.startScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:651) ~[spring-context-support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.start(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:714) ~[spring-context-support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

Here is my `quartz-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="scheduler" name="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
       <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
        <!-- <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="functionalDataSource"/></property> -->
        <property name="nonTransactionalDataSource"><ref bean="functionalNonTransactionalDataSource"/></property>
        <property name="transactionManager"><ref bean="transactionManager"/></property>

        <!-- This name is persisted as SCHED_NAME in db. for local testing could
            change to unique name to avoid collision with dev server -->
        <property name="schedulerName" value="quartzScheduler" />

        <!-- Will update database cron triggers to what is in this jobs file on
            each deploy. Replaces all previous trigger and job data that was in the database.
            YMMV -->
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="false" />

        <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Mixing spring version 4.3.3 and 3.0.3 jars. Never mix version of a framework...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for responding. My spring version is 4.1.6. and Quartz - 2.2.1

Comment: No it isn't... Your stracktrace clearly indicates that yu are mixing the versions I mentioned. `spring-context-support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE` and `spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE`. If you have 4.1.6 in the mix that makes things even worse.

Comment: But, without quartz it is working alright :(

Comment: Sigh... Read... My first comment. You are mixing spring versions NEVER mix versions of a framework. It has nothing to do with quartz. It is the fact that you try to use an older spring jar for the quartz support with a newer versions. Again NEVER use different versions of a framework. The jars should all be from the same version.